# UILocalNotification sound settings in iPad simulator

Tags: ios, notifications, settings, simulator, audio

I'm testing my app on iPad simulator. But have some problem with notification sound play.

Notification sound would be played When the app is running on foreground, but not on background. It shows a banner type notification without any sound. I'm wondering about if the notification settings in iPad simulator determine this situation. The iPhone's settings app has 'notifications' menu and we can set notification types-none,banner,alert- and sound etc. I can't figure out iPad device settings app because don't have iPad :(

The iPhone simulator and iPhone device work properly. But not iPad simulator.

```
 -(void) registerNoti {
      localNotif.fireDate = noti.date;
      localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


      //Payload
      localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.textLabel.text];
      localNotif.alertAction = @"Run App";
      localNotif.soundName = @"sound.mp3";
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
 }
```

Is there any way to figure out iPad simulator notification sound problem? Or can I just ignore this problem and would it be all ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining full path to mp3 file:

`localNotif.soundName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];`

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an iPad (or a friend with an iPad who can test for you), then don't release this app for iPad. Never rely on the simulator. You *must* ultimately test on a device. And your question is one example of why: you're now programming by guesswork, which is asking for trouble. You have no idea what your app really does (because "really" can only mean "on a device").